# WPF combobox.SelectedItem doesn't update if I use DataTemplate to bind the VM to a View

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I found that WPF `combobox.SelectedItem` doesn't get updated if I use DataTemplate to bind the **VM** to a **View**, but it will update if I use a **View** directly. Here's my code.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SalesPeriodVM}">
        <local:View />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

**View.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SalesPeriods}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs ( code behind)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    int currCount = 0;

    private void GotfocusClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currCount = currCount+1;
        salesVM.SelectedItem = salesVM.SalesPeriods[currCount % salesVM.SalesPeriods.Count];
    }

}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SyncfusionWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SyncfusionWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SalesPeriodVM x:Name="salesVM"/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabCOntrol1" Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem Header="Item2" GotFocus="GotfocusClick">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Item1">
                    <!--<local:View /> this works-->        
                <local:SalesPeriodVM /> <!--this doesn't work-->
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My ViewModel code:

```
public class SalesPeriodVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<SalesPeriodV> salesPeriods = new ObservableCollection<SalesPeriodV>();
    public ObservableCollection<SalesPeriodV> SalesPeriods
    {
        get { return salesPeriods; }
        set { salesPeriods = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SalesPeriods"); }
    }
    private SalesPeriodV selectedItem = new SalesPeriodV();
    public SalesPeriodV SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set { selectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }


    }

    public SalesPeriodVM()
    {
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 1, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 2, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 3, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 4, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 5, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 6, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 7, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 8, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 9, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 10, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 11, Year = 1 });
        SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 12, Year = 1 });

        SelectedItem = SalesPeriods[1];
    }

    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
        }
    }
}

public class SalesPeriodV : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int month, year;

    public int Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set
        {
            if (year != value)
            {
                year = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get { return month; }
        set
        {
            if (month != value)
            {
                month = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Month");
            }
        }
    }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0:D2}.{1}", Month, Year);
    }

    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
        }
    }
}
```

So, if I embed `<local:SalesPeriodVM />` inside `Item1`, then when the `Item2` gains focus, the `combobox.SelectedItem` in View doesn't get updated. Bear in mind that `salesVM.SelectedItem` does get set. Just that the UI not updated.

What is really interesting is that if I comment out `<local:SalesPeriodVM />`, and instead embed `<local:View />` inside `Item1`, then when I click on the `Item2` tab, the `combobox.SelectedItem` in View gets updated!

**I thought both the embedment of `<local:SalesPeriodVM />` and `<local:View />` should be equivalent, but why this is not the case?** Any idea how to make sure that `ComboBox.SelectedItem` is updated if I have to use `<local:SalesPeriodVM />`?

Comment: @dymanoid, I've reformatted the code; `salesVM` is the local instance property of the type `local:SalesPeriodVM` in `MainWindow` class

Comment: @dymanoid not sure I understand you. What do you mean by "bindings sources are now the second viewmodel", your second view model refers to ? Throughout all of the `DataContext` there is only 1 VM, and that is `SalesPeriodVM`.

Comment: @dymanoid, I think you should run my code ( it's self-contained) , and try to alternate between `<local:SalesPeriodVM />` and `<local:View />` as suggested, and you will see that the output is different, even though they should be the same ( as per my question)

Comment: You have two view-model instances in your setup, as I mentioned before. The first instance is the one you set as a `DataContext` for the window. The second one is the `DataContext` of the `View` located in the second `TabItem`. Please read carefully about the data-templating concept.

Comment: @dymanoid I see what you mean. Let me update this question later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [dymanoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210274/wpf-combobox-selecteditem-doesnt-update-if-i-use-datatemplate-to-bind-the-vm-to/50348023#comment87446497_50210274), the issue is that there are two separate instance `local:SalesPeriodVM`.

The first instance is the one set as a `DataContext` for the window. The second one is the `DataContext` of the `View` located in the second `TabItem`.

So what gets displayed is the `DataContext` of the `View` located in the second `TabItem`, but what gets changed is the first one set as a `DataContext` for the `Window`.

This explains why the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` is not updated.